# Python, basic question: How do I download multiple url's with urllib.request.urlretrieve

Tags: python

I have the following fully functional, working code:

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile

url = "http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sop"
filename = "C:/test/archive.zip"
destinationPath = "C:/test"

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
sourceZip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')

for name in sourceZip.namelist():
    sourceZip.extract(name, destinationPath)
sourceZip.close()
```

It will work perfect a few times, but because the server I am retrieving the file from has some limits, I get this error once I reach that daily limit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 150, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1591, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

How do I alter the script, so that it includes a list of multiple url's, instead of one single url, and the script keeps trying to download from the list until one succeeds, and then continues with the unzip. I just need one successful download.

Apologies for being very new to Python but I can't figure this one out. I'm assuming I have to change the variable to look something like this:

```
url = {
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2soe",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sod",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2soc",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sob",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2soa",
}
```

and then changing this line into some sort of loop:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to put your urls in a list, then loop through that list and try each one. You catch but ignore exceptions they throw, and break the loop once one succeeds. Try this:

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile

urls = ["http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sop", "other url", "another url"]
filename = "C:/test/test.zip"
destinationPath = "C:/test"

for url in urls:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
        sourceZip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

for name in sourceZip.namelist():
    sourceZip.extract(name, destinationPath)
sourceZip.close()
```

Comment: This did -exactly- what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile

urllist = ("http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sop",
            "another",
            "yet another",
            "etc")

filename = "C:/test/test.zip"
destinationPath = "C:/test"

for url in urllist:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    sourceZip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')

    for name in sourceZip.namelist():
        sourceZip.extract(name, destinationPath)
    sourceZip.close()
    break
```

This will work assuming you just want to try them each once until one works, then stop.

Answer (score 0):

For a full-fledged distributed tasks you can checkout [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) and their retry mechanism [Celery-retry](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=retry#retrying-a-task-if-something-fails)

or you can have a look at [Retry-decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary),
Example:

```
import time

# Retry decorator with exponential backoff
def retry(tries, delay=3, backoff=2):
  """Retries a function or method until it returns True.

  delay sets the initial delay, and backoff sets how much the delay should
  lengthen after each failure. backoff must be greater than 1, or else it
  isn't really a backoff. tries must be at least 0, and delay greater than
  0."""

  if backoff <= 1:
    raise ValueError("backoff must be greater than 1")

  tries = math.floor(tries)
  if tries < 0:
    raise ValueError("tries must be 0 or greater")

  if delay <= 0:
    raise ValueError("delay must be greater than 0")

  def deco_retry(f):
    def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
      mtries, mdelay = tries, delay # make mutable

      rv = f(*args, **kwargs) # first attempt
      while mtries > 0:
        if rv == True: # Done on success
          return True

        mtries -= 1      # consume an attempt
        time.sleep(mdelay) # wait...
        mdelay *= backoff  # make future wait longer

        rv = f(*args, **kwargs) # Try again

      return False # Ran out of tries :-(

    return f_retry # true decorator -> decorated function
  return deco_retry  # @retry(arg[, ...]) -> true decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urls = [
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2soe",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sod",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2soc",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2sob",
"http://url.com/archive.zip?key=7UCxcuCzFpYeu7tz18JgGZFAAgXQ2soa",
]

for u in urls:
   urllib.request.urlretrieve(u,filename)
   ... rest of code ...
```