# Bypass exception to always execute command?

Tags: python

The following code works almost perfect, thanks to the help received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016252/python-basic-question-how-do-i-download-multiple-urls-with-urllib-request-urlr):

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile
import subprocess

urls = ["http://url.com/archive1.zip", "http://url.com/archive2.zip", "http://url.com/archive3.zip"]
filename = "C:/test/test.zip"
destinationPath = "C:/test"

for url in urls:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
        sourceZip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

for name in sourceZip.namelist():
    sourceZip.extract(name, destinationPath)
sourceZip.close()

subprocess.call(r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\test\test.exe"')
```

Except that when none of the url's successfully download, the final subprocess.call command never gets executed and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    for name in sourceZip.namelist():
NameError: name 'sourceZip' is not defined
```

I have been playing around a bit with the try: and except, but can not come to a working solution. I believe it is because the try: except command has to be inside the sourceZip loop, but since the sourceZip variable never gets declared, it fails. How would I alter this code to have the subprocess.call always get executed at the end regardless whether the download is successfull or not? (very new to Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `sourceZip = None` prior to the `for url in urls` line.  Then test if `sourceZip is None` after the `for` loop to determine if you were able to successfully fetch the file.  For example:

```
sourceZip = None

for url in urls:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)
        sourceZip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

if sourceZip is not None:
    for name in sourceZip.namelist():
        sourceZip.extract(name, destinationPath)
    sourceZip.close()

subprocess.call(r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\test\test.exe"')
```

Comment: Almost works I think, except I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    for name in sourceZip.namelist():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'namelist'

Comment: I promise I didn't see your answer.

Comment: @Paul: Then you're not using my code... is it possible that you only execute the `for name in sourceZip.namelist()` loop if sourceZip *is* `None`?  Make sure that you're only executing that loop if `sourceZip is not None`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had some user right issues and I actually was not saving the edits. Your code worked -perfect- ! Thanks so much!

Comment: That would do it.  No problem, I'm glad my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize sourceZip to None. Then check if it is not none do the extraction and closing.

Comment: This almost works except I get an error when it tries to extract "none", stopping the script. This is the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'namelist'